# Progressive Web App (PWA) redirect page into standalone mode

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have `PWA` and I can run it as standalone (if user clicks icon on a device) or I can run as normal website (if user enter `URL` directly into web browser).
Is it possible to redirect page (open as standalone) if user open it as non standalone?
My manifest file already contain standalone parameter:

```
 "display": "standalone"
```

I need something to start with.

Comment: You cannot stop a user from using the browser to view you PWA (url). They could even switch to the browser view from your full screen PWA. Realistically, if the user has installed your PWA and has a shorcut on their desktop, they will use that most of the time. Very few would type the URL into the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you need to "install" the pwa on the user device first.

By clicking the icon on the device (meaning you already installed the app there) you open the PWA that will be rendered as described in the web manifest (standalone in your case).

If you wouldn't have already installed the pwa on the device, you would have the same behaviour you are getting on your desktop by accessing the web site with the browser.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

---

**UPDATE**

The answer to your question (in the comment) is no (from a desktop browser). Chrome on an Android device uses/opens directly the PWA version, if installed of course. This is due to the Android Intent Filters that enable this.

But this is not the case from a desktop browser, where the user accesses the web site by entering the url manually. Maybe in the future it might change, but at the moment it is not possible.

Comment: yes I have PWA installed on a device. By this point you have two ways to open this app/website. First by clicking app icon (standalone) and second just by opening chrome browser and typing url manually. My question is is it possible to redirect into standalone mode if user opens via chrome browser

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome on desktop, if the PWA is installed and the user opens the app in the browser, there's a "To open this link, choose an app" link at top right on the address bar, between the password manager key and the bookmarks star - you could point that out to the user. Clicking that link offers a button to open the PWA and close the browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means when some user open pwa from mobile it's go preloader then redirect to other external site in mode standalone, like redirect to google.com and don't load pwa body instead, only preloader then quick redirect... In browser it's behaviour the same after pwa is loading.